# Ruby On Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't figure out how to get the following routes.  Here's an extract from my routes.rb file:

```
  map.resources :treatments
  map.root :controller => "home"
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.connect ':action', :controller => 'home' # replaces the need to manually map pure actions to a default controller

  map.resources :bookings
  map.resource :dashboard
  map.resource :home
```

Now I do realise that the ordering matters, but I can't seem to get them to work correctly.

What I want is so http://localhost:3000/bookings/new actually takes you to an action http://localhost:3000/bookings/signmeup if you're either not signed in, or haven't got a login.  The problem is that if I change my routes around, when I attempt to create a new booking *after* I have logged in, then it doesn't POST the form submission and just takes me back to the view page.  This is definitely because of the routes as if I rearrange map.resources :bookings to be before all of them, then it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you want your resource routes to come before the generic `:controller/:action/:id` routes (in fact, I go so far as to delete the generic routes entirely), since routes that are defined first take precedence over the ones that are assigned later.

As for redirecting to /bookings/signmeup if the user is not logged in, you should handle that with a `before_filter`:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_login

  # ...

  protected
    # This is a GENERIC example; change to fit your authentication method
    def check_login
      unless user_is_logged_in
        redirect_to ...
      end
    end
end
```